# 自クライアントでPHPをもちいてMy SQLとPHPファイルの生成

Tags: php, mysql

自PC上でPHPをもちいてMy SQLとPHPファイルをコードから生成することは可能ですか？

macOS MAMP

Comment: see also https://teratail.com/questions/297393

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 自PC上でPHPをもちいてMy SQLとPHPファイルをコードから生成することは可能ですか？

MySQL を生成するという文言からは `mysqld` とか `mysqldump` とかの実行ファイルであるとかヘルプファイルであるとかを作るとしか読めませんが MySQL 開発部隊が PHP を使ってこれらを作っているとは思えません。普通にコンパイラやリンカを使って作っているでしょう。

マルチポスト先でも質問の意図が理解できなくて読者が困っています。まあ普通 Web Front/Back を作るのであれば「アクセスするだけでデータベースファイルや PHP 実行ファイルが作られる」ような構造はセキュリティ的にあり得ません。

こういう場(Q&A 掲示板)で質問するならもうちょっと勉強して「質疑応答が成立する」程度の文章が書けるくらい知識を付けてください。